# how to pass object to test method in nunit in c#

Tags: c#, object, testing, nunit

How can I pass an object while testing with NUnit in c#

Hi
I have written some code and am trying to use NUnit Test. When I pass int or string it works but I dont know how to use this test method with objects...
Lets explain exactly what I wan to to do: I have a method that gets an input as **Income** which is a class and other than its functionality, returns a tuple; a Boolean ***successRsult*** that shows if it has finished the job and an ***errormessage*** which shows the error message in case of error and null if no error. this is the code:

```
public (bool successResult, string errorMessage) Create(Income income)
{
    bool successResult;
    string errorMessage;

    try
    {
        if ((income.Date is null) || (income.Amount == 0) || income.Payee_ID == 0))  
        {
            errorMessage = "Fill all the required fields!";
            successResult = false;

        }
        else
        {
            (successResult, errorMessage) = incomeDAL.Create(income);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
        successResult = false;
    }
    return (successResult, errorMessage);
}
```

I want to create a test method. named ***IncomeCreateTest()*** which tests the function of this
now please help me how can I write a test procedure for this create function. what I need is some testcases; this test cases should be in Income(input), bool(output) and string(output); but what I can not do is to pass testcases which include Income object. this is my test code:

```
namespace Test_Layer
{
    [TestFixture]

    public class NunitTests
    {
        Income income1 = new Income
        {
            Date = "01-01-2000",
            Amount = 1000,
            Payee_ID = 1,
            Payor = "Bob",
            Description = "Contract no 1"
        };

        Income income2 = new Income
        {
            Date = "02-01-2000",
            Amount = 1500,
            Payee_ID = 2,
            Payor = "Jimmy",
            Description = "Contract no 2"
        };

        [Test]

        public void IncomeCreateTest(Income income)
        {
            Family_Budget_BLL.IncomeBLL bLL = new 
            Family_Budget_BLL.IncomeBLL();
            List<Income> incomes = new List<Income> { income1, income2 };

            

            foreach (var item in incomes)
            {

                (bool res1, string res2) = bLL.Create(income);

                Assert.That(res1, Is.True);
                Assert.That(res2, Is.Null);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

You can see that I am trying to pass expected inputs and outputs to my test method using a list of incomes and a foreach loop.
finally this code does not work!

Comment: Are you asking how to pass objects as parameters to NUnit tests? Could you post some code that works for `int` or `string` and show what you've tried for `Customer`?

Comment: Are you looking for [TestCaseSource](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html)? This can construct arbitrary data to be passed to a test method.

Comment: edited.... can you pls answer now.

Comment: to Klaus: I think yes ... maybe I need something to use instead of a [TestCase]